# ValueTuple not working in Razor views with MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, c#-7.0

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 project in Visual Studio 2017 and after successfully adding C# 7 support (which has worked for me so far), I tried using tuples in my Razor views, but I got a surprising error message:

```
CS0433: The type 'ValueTuple<T1, T2>' exists in both 'System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' and 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
```

Of course I have installed `System.ValueTuple` as a nuget package but this error says there's another implementation of that inside `mscorlib` itself - how does that make any sense? After all, if I remove the nuget package from my project, `ValueTuple` can't be found anymore. I'm targeting .NET Framework 4.5.2 and using the latest version of all packages that come from ASP.NET.

This problem doesn't even seem to be related to the new C# 7 syntax, it's caused just by trying to use the `ValueTuple` type:

```
ValueTuple<int, int> tuple;
```

I'm even more confused by the error that Visual Studio's IntelliSense gives me, which says that `ValueTuple` isn't referenced and to use it I have to add a reference to `System.Runtime`. Installing that helps calm Visual Studio but doesn't make any difference at runtime.

Comment: "but I got a surprising error message" - at what point did you get that? On build, or when you try to run? I'm guessing that it's when the Razor views are compiled with the *actual* framework (which I suspect is 4.7, as per my answer).

Comment: When I run it and get the usual yellow screen of death because Razor compilation fails.

Comment: Right. That would certainly tie in with the suspicion I raised in my answer - if you're compiling the Razor code against .NET 4.7, you *will* see this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Of course I have installed System.ValueTuple as a nuget package

I suspect that's the problem. My guess is that even though you're *targeting* .NET 4.5.2, you're *running* on a .NET 4.7 system, and that includes `System.ValueTuple` in mscorlib.

I suggest you remove the package dependency on the `System.ValueTuple` package, and update your target framework to .NET 4.7 (as you seem to be running on that anyway)... if that change doesn't break other things, of course...

Comment: I'm not sure how these newer .NET Framework version work, so it's possible. But I'm only running this on my local machine, I can't actually use 4.7 because it's not supported yet by my web hosting provider - only 4.6. If this is the case that 4.7 replaces the old versions, how can it break apps that target 4.5 with no regards for backwards compatibility? This seems like a really serious problem to me that upgrading to 4.7 would break everything. I assumed that targeting 4.5 would still ensure the correct behavior.

Comment: @Neme: I think if you could force-build the Razor views locally while still targeting the 4.5.2 reference assemblies, it might be okay. I honestly don't know the details of how this is meant to work - I agree it's a nasty situation. Are you able to try targeting 4.7 temporarily just to see if that solves the issue locally? (And I assume you're only seeing the problem locally anyway? Have you tried to deploy the "broken" code to a test environment in your web hosting provder? My guess is that it may well work...)

Comment: After installing the 4.7 SDK and retargeting the project, it does solve the problem for me. I don't know yet how to build Razor views but that sounds like a good idea to me anyway if that's possible. I was immediately suspicious when I found out that parts of my app would be compiled at different times in different places - and dynamically at runtime. I'm still new to ASP.NET as a desktop developer and don't even have a test environment. I think I will probably just give up tuples after all.

Comment: @Neme: Unfortunately I know even less about "full" ASP.NET than I do about ASP.NET Core, but hopefully at least the *idea* of pre-compiling the Razor views will be a starting point for research for you...

Comment: On a second thought, I thought I might not need tuples at all since what I was trying to do is a nice way to do foreach with an index - I created my own type with custom deconstruction and for some reason C# still requires `ValueTuple` even though I'm not using it.

Comment: @Neme: Yes, unfortunately deconstruction *currently* requires a reference for `System.ValueTuple`. It's being removed in C# 7.2 - see https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/18629